# Rendering accentuated characters from TrueType font with java looks wrong on certain systems

Tags: java, fonts, awt, truetype

I am having an issue converting characters for a TrueType font (Arial for example) to `java.awt.Shape` for further manual rendering (as EPS but it does not matter).

I have broken down the program that does it into small processes to find out where the problem comes from and it looks to me like the problem is coming from the process of loading the glyph from the font.

I am using the following code snippet to load the font (Arial, from msttcore package) and convert the character `Ö` as a `Shape` that I can use later on:

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24);
AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString("Ö");
attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, font, 0, "Ö".length());
FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(null, false, false);
TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(attributedString.getIterator(), fontRenderContext);
Shape shape = layout.getOutline(null);
```

I have also tried using the following code snippet but it gives me the same results:

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24);
FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(null, false, false);
GlyphVector glyphVector = font.createGlyphVector(fontRenderContext, text);
Shape shape = glyphVector.getOutline();
```

After that, I use the `shape.getPathIterator(null)` and iterate over the segments it gives me to print the point coordinates. I do that on three different systems:

- Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) where I take care of using the Font() constructor allowing me to point at the right arial.ttf file, to avoid my snippet using the system's built-in Arial font.
- An Amazon AWS linux distribution that looks based on Fedora
- An Amazon AWS linux distribution based on Ubuntu server

When generating the `java.awt.Shape` on my Mac, the generated EPS file looks right. When generating the `java.awt.Shape` on the Linux machines, it appears that some point coordinates are different than the ones generated on my Mac.

- The **O** part coordinates of the 'Ö' are different but only to an extent where it only looks like rounding errors and isn't perceptible to my eye:
- The **¨** part however looks very weird and the point coordinates differ much more than the rounding errors.

See the following picture:

[image: Both glyphs on the same picture]

In green is the path from the Shape generated on my Mac, in red the path from the Shape generated on the Fedora-like computer.

Because both overlap well on the **O** part, it looks like a bit darker green. But you can see that the **¨** part is very different. It's not even centered for the red path...

**Summary of my experiments:**

- Java version/distribution does not look to affect that issue.
- It looks like a common problem with all accentuated characters (so far: ÖÄÅÜ).
- I have the same problem with the Times New Roman font.

I think I have already tried many things without success and I don't really understand why this happens and would be thankful for any tips.

---

Here is the smallest complete code snippet I can give you that shows the problem:

```
package Experiments;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.AttributedString;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24);
        AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString("Ö");
        attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, font, 0, "Ö".length());
        FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = new FontRenderContext(null, false, false);
        TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(attributedString.getIterator(), fontRenderContext);
        Shape shape = layout.getOutline(null);
        PathIterator it = shape.getPathIterator(null);
        double[] points = new double[6];
        double x = 0, y = 0;

        while (!it.isDone())
        {
            double x1 = points[0], y1 = points[1];
            double x2 = points[2], y2 = points[3];
            double x3 = points[4], y3 = points[5];

            switch (it.currentSegment(points))
            {
                case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                    System.out.println("close");
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
                    // Convert to cubic curve
                    x3 = x2;
                    y3 = y2;
                    x2 = x1 + 1 / 3f * (x2 - x1);
                    y2 = y1 + 1 / 3f * (y2 - y1);
                    x1 = x + 2 / 3f * (x1 - x);
                    y1 = y + 2 / 3f * (y1 - y);
                case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
                    System.out.println("curve: " + x1 + "," + y1 + "," + x2 + "," + y2 + "," + x3 + "," + y3);
                    x = x3;
                    y = y3;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                    System.out.println("lineto: " + x1 + "," + y1);
                    x = x1;
                    y = y1;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                    System.out.println("moveto: " + x1 + "," + y1);
                    x = x1;
                    y = y1;
                    break;
            }
            it.next();
        }
    }
}
```

The output on my Mac is:

```
moveto: 0.0,0.0
curve: 0.7734375230502337,-5.57812516624108,0.7734374884748831,-5.57812491687946,0.0,0.0
curve: 0.7734375230502337,-8.429687751224265,1.925781272817403,-13.451171899039764,3.45703125,-15.064453125
curve: 4.988281295634806,-16.677734423079528,6.96484378608875,-17.484375,9.38671875,-17.484375
curve: 10.97265629726462,-17.484375,12.402343768975697,-17.105468738707714,13.67578125,-16.34765625
curve: 14.949218787951395,-15.589843727415428,15.91992188495351,-14.533203104801942,16.587890625,-13.177734375
curve: 17.25585939490702,-11.822265584603883,17.58984375,-10.28515622438863,17.58984375,-8.56640625
curve: 17.58984375,-6.8242186980787665,17.23828123952262,-5.265624979510903,16.53515625,-3.890625
curve: 15.832031229045242,-2.5156249590218067,14.835937480791472,-1.4746093644644134,13.546875,-0.767578125
curve: 12.257812461582944,-0.06054685392882675,10.867187477764674,0.29296875,9.375,0.29296875
curve: 7.757812451804057,0.29296875,6.3124999810243025,-0.09765626164153218,5.0390625,-0.87890625
curve: 3.765624962048605,-1.6601562732830644,2.800781240221113,-2.7265625201398507,2.14453125,-4.078125
close
moveto: 1.16015625,-6.10546875
curve: 2.7226562965661287,-7.589843794237822,2.7226562267169356,-8.343750000349246,1.16015625,-8.3671875
curve: 2.7226562965661287,-6.2734374376013875,4.060546891589183,-4.630859357246663,5.173828125,-3.439453125
curve: 6.287109408178367,-2.248046839493327,7.683593775029294,-1.65234375,9.36328125,-1.65234375
curve: 11.074218800989911,-1.65234375,12.482421891472768,-2.2539062679279596,13.587890625,-3.45703125
curve: 14.693359407945536,-4.660156285855919,15.24609375,-6.367187532945536,15.24609375,-8.578125
curve: 15.24609375,-9.976562541676685,15.009765617956873,-11.197265640541445,14.537109375,-12.240234375
curve: 14.064453110913746,-13.283203156082891,13.373046861437615,-14.091796883556526,12.462890625,-14.666015625
curve: 11.55273434787523,-15.240234392113052,10.531249983119778,-15.52734375,9.3984375,-15.52734375
curve: 7.789062452036887,-15.52734375,6.404296857712325,-14.974609358527232,5.244140625,-13.869140625
close
moveto: 3.50390625,-12.2109375
lineto: 6.046875,-18.234375
lineto: 6.046875,-20.63671875
lineto: 8.25,-20.63671875
close
moveto: 8.25,-18.234375
lineto: 10.41796875,-18.234375
lineto: 10.41796875,-20.63671875
lineto: 12.62109375,-20.63671875
close
```

On the fedora-like computer:

```
moveto: 0.0,0.0
curve: 0.7708333563059568,-5.583333499729633,0.7708333218470216,-5.583333250135183,0.0,0.0
curve: 0.7708333563059568,-8.427083584479988,1.921875022817403,-13.447916690725833,3.453125,-15.0625
curve: 4.984375045634806,-16.677083381451666,6.963541702833027,-17.484375,9.390625,-17.484375
curve: 10.973958380520344,-17.484375,12.403645852347836,-17.106770822079852,13.6796875,-16.3515625
curve: 14.955729204695672,-15.596354144159704,15.92708334326744,-14.539062479743734,16.59375,-13.1796875
curve: 17.26041668653488,-11.820312459487468,17.59375,-10.28124997438863,17.59375,-8.5625
curve: 17.59375,-6.822916614823043,17.24218748952262,-5.265624979510903,16.5390625,-3.890625
curve: 15.835937479045242,-2.5156249590218067,14.838541647419333,-1.4739583227783442,13.546875,-0.765625
curve: 12.255208294838667,-0.05729164555668831,10.864583311136812,0.296875,9.375,0.296875
curve: 7.760416618548334,0.296875,6.315104147652164,-0.09375001164153218,5.0390625,-0.875
curve: 3.763020795304328,-1.6562500232830644,2.796874990221113,-2.723958353511989,2.140625,-4.078125
close
moveto: 1.15625,-6.109375
curve: 2.7187500465661287,-7.5885417107492685,2.7187499767169356,-8.343750000465661,1.15625,-8.375
curve: 2.7187500465661287,-6.2812499376013875,4.057291683275253,-4.638020815560594,5.171875,-3.4453125
curve: 6.286458366550505,-2.2526041311211884,7.682291691657156,-1.65625,9.359375,-1.65625
curve: 11.078125051222742,-1.65625,12.489583349786699,-2.2578125179279596,13.59375,-3.4609375
curve: 14.697916699573398,-4.664062535855919,15.25,-6.369791699573398,15.25,-8.578125
curve: 15.25,-9.973958374932408,15.013020826270804,-11.195312515599653,14.5390625,-12.2421875
curve: 14.065104152541608,-13.289062531199306,13.372395819751546,-14.098958341870457,12.4609375,-14.671875
curve: 11.549479139503092,-15.244791683740914,10.531249983236194,-15.53125,9.40625,-15.53125
curve: 7.791666618548334,-15.53125,6.4036458160262555,-14.979166650213301,5.2421875,-13.875
close
moveto: 3.5,-12.21875
lineto: 6.625,-18.0
lineto: 6.625,-20.390625
lineto: 8.828125,-20.390625
lineto: 8.828125,-18.0
close
moveto: 6.625,-18.0
lineto: 11.0,-18.0
lineto: 11.0,-20.390625
lineto: 13.203125,-20.390625
lineto: 13.203125,-18.0
close
```

You already have my thanks if you have read until here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on earth are you bothering with Arial? The "free" msttcorefonts version is abandonware that hasn't received fixes for years. It is optimized for a font rendering system that does not exist anymore (It is well known nowadays that Microsoft used wrong metadata values in those files to workaround bugs in its then bleeding-edge system).

Use a modern font intended for cross-platform use and with licensing that actually allow redistribution and derivatives instead (see DejaVu or Google font library). Your shapes *are* derivatives.

Old java on OSX was maintained by Apple and probably uses Apple-specific font engine.
Old java on other systems (as do the Oracle downloads) uses a proprietary font engine.
OpenJDK uses freetype (Oracle didn't dare changing the official jdk for fear of breaking apps relying on its old engine warts. A shame, freetype *is* well-maintained).

Expecting all of them to give the exactly same shaping results is an exercise in futility. And the more complex and old the font is, the more likely they will diverge (old fonts include old metadata new fonts do not, and depending on the font engine it will try to do something with this old data, or not. Font formats even include Apple and Windows-specific metadata that will be read or ignored depending on the font engine used).

Smart font formats are wonderful…

Comment: Thanks for your input, you look to have much more knowledge about fonts than I have. That's interesting information that may explain my troubles. Testing with different fonts hasn't yet been fully investigated, would you recommend any font for testing purpose?
As for the reasons why I use Arial, it has been in my client specification (I guess because people are used to it) and I haven't tried to discuss the issue. In shorthand, they sell products with text on it and I guess people "like" to buy stuff with Arial text on.

Comment: For testing purposes, Linux Libertine (http://www.linuxlibertine.org/) and DejaVu (http://dejavu-fonts.org) are probably good choices. They're both modern, but mature font projects that spent a lot of time including a rich set of diacritics, and tested the result on more than Windows systems. And if you find bugs in the fonts, both of them will fix them after reporting.

Comment: Ok thanks Nim, I accept your answer since it's the one that led us on the right path.

Comment: Cross-referencing to a related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21292251/2074605

Answer (score 2):

nim's answer led us on the way, so I accepted it.

I'll only document here what we found out in our investigations.

With a little of black-box testing we realized that the problem vanishes when using bigger font sizes. Then, using very big font sizes (25000px) we got the upper points of the glyphs getting negative coordinates which look suspiciously like integer overflow side-effects.

I haven't tried to find the font engine's source code, but with the black-box testing I can suspect that the font engine used in our java version somewhere uses integer when reading the glyphs from the font which gets pretty big rounding errors when using small font sizes and overflow errors when using big font sizes.

To fix our problem and change our production code as least as possible we have decided to always load the font with a font size of 100px and then to scale the Shape with AffineTransform to the desired size.

We haven't changed the font as suggested by nim's answer because we are trying to do a fix as minimal as possible but we keep it in out minds that there are much better alternatives to msttcore fonts (Google Fonts lib being one (By the way, we also had rounding errors with the Google fonts even though a bit less than with msttcore fonts)).

Comment: Happy to have been of use. What may have also helped you is that much of the OpenType glyph distortion magic (to snap glyphs to the pixel grid) only occurs at small sizes