# Loading some TrueType Font from TTF file in Java causes FontFormatException: Font name not found

Tags: java, fonts, awt, truetype

I am attempting to create a java.awt.Font instance from a TTF file on my system, but only some fonts are able to load without error. The code below is some test code I found online. When run on my system, it is able to load 285 fonts successfully (ex. Arial.ttf), but fails on 83 fonts, (ex. AmericanTypewriter.ttf).

All errors are of the form `FontFormatException: Font name not found` with no embedded cause.

Are there known issues with java.awt.Font and format compatibility? I can't find anything after much Googling.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rootPath = "/Library/Fonts";

        File root = new File(rootPath);
        if (root.canRead()) {
            String[] fontFiles = root.list();

            Font font = null;
            for (String fontFile : fontFiles) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(fontFile);
                    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(root + "/" + fontFile));
                    System.out.println(font);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My environment is Java 7, OS X Mavericks (10.9.1).

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so after some digging, it turns out that this problem is due to a bug (feature!) in the java.awt implementation. Namely, loading a physical TrueType font fails if the font file's name table does not include family name and full name records.

To identify the problem, I used GrepCode to trace backward from the relevant exception in OpenJDK's AWT implementation. Once I had discovered the name table issue, I used [ttx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fonttools/), a no-frills TrueType metadata editor to add the name entries Java looks for. Ex:

```
<namerecord nameID="1" platformID="3" platEncID="1" langID="0x409">
  American Typewriter
</namerecord>
<namerecord nameID="4" platformID="3" platEncID="1" langID="0x409">
  American Typewriter
</namerecord>
```

The new TTF files generated by ttx could now be opened by Java. Yay!

Comment: I had a similar problem, but the font loaded properly in Java6 (Eclipse) but not in Java7 (terminal). There seems to be a difference in the implementation between Java6 and 7 as well...

Answer (score 3):

This is an Oracle JDK/OpenJDK feature ([bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048724)).

The problem is caused by `sun.font.TrueTypeFont` and its lack of support for Mac TrueType font names.

`TrueTypeFont.java` contains a check for reading the name table of a TrueType font to only read the Microsoft platform ID name `(platformID == 3)` and not the Mac platform ID `(platformID == 1)`. In many cases, truetype fonts included on OSX only have names with a `platformID` of 1. Because of this, the `initNames()` method does not set a value for either `familyName` or `fullName` and the code after `initNames()` runs checks to see if they are null (which they are of course) and throws the `Font name not found` exception.

On Apple JDK (1.6 and maybe 1.5?), Apple didn't use TrueTypeFont as the FontHandler. They had their own implementation which is called `sun.font.AppleNativeFont`. You can't even use `sun.font.TrueTypeFont` on Apple JDK because it will always use the `sun.font.AppleNativeFont` handler, which has support for both Mac and Microsoft platform IDs.

It appears that `sun.font.AppleNativeFont` doesn't exist in OpenJDK or Oracle JDK, even though Apple "donated" the code to Oracle.

It would be handy from a continuity point of view to include `sun.font.AppleNativeFont` in OpenJDK/Oracle JDK. It would be even better if `TrueTypeFont.java` was improved to include support for Mac TrueType fonts.

**UPDATE: WORKAROUND SOLUTION.**

One of the patches in the comments below was submitted to the OpenJDK repository. If you clone the repository with the right revision, you can get the patched files.

`hg clone -r 8b05f9b91765 http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk`

Copy these following files from `jdk/src/shared/classes/sun/font`:

```
TrueTypeFont.java
LCIDMap.java
AppleLangID.java
```

To the same directory in the trunk of a current JDK (I used jdk8-b132), compile it and you will have Mac font support. You may also want to apply this patch which was made after the Mac font patch:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/rev/3dabb2f78e73

Voila!

Comment: A couple of people posted patchesback in 2011 that were never included.

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/2d-dev/2011-March/001922.html

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk6-dev/2011-January/002230.html

And here is someone who has asked for it to be fixed again in 2014:

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/awt-dev/2014-January/006860.html