# Android: FontFormatException while adding font in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, android-fonts, android-typeface

I am dealing with the Japanese font. I found a good Japanese fonts named `noto sans cjk jp` but it is too heavy to use for each textview in Android (16MB). I convert it from `oft` to `ttf` by using online converter: 
[Cloud convert](https://cloudconvert.com/otf-to-ttf) 
[Files conversion](http://www.files-conversion.com/font/otf) 
[Fonts 2 you](http://www.fonts2u.com/font-converter.html) 
It turns out to be more suitable now (around 8KB). However, when I add it to my application, it cause the error `FontFormatException`

```
java.awt.FontFormatException: Font name not found
at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.init(TrueTypeFont.java:573)
at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:191)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.createFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2461)
at java.awt.Font.<init>(Font.java:615)
at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:969)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:877)
at android.graphics.FontFamily_Delegate.nAddFontFromAsset(FontFamily_Delegate.java:343)
at android.graphics.FontFamily.nAddFontFromAsset(FontFamily.java)
at android.graphics.FontFamily.addFontFromAsset(FontFamily.java:70)
at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:185)
at com.example.user.fontchange.Typefaces.get(Typefaces.java:18)
at com.example.user.fontchange.CustomView.<init>(CustomView.java:18)
at com.example.user.fontchange.CustomView.<init>(CustomView.java:13)
```

My questions are: 
1/ Is there anyway we can check the converted font is correct or not? 
2/ Anyone knows how to make Android Studio accepts my font name? I also found a link [Loading some TrueType Font from TTF file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268694/loading-some-truetype-font-from-ttf-file-in-java-causes-fontformatexception-fon) but the answer does not solve my problem.

## EDIT 1:

Here is my `CustomView` to add new font:

```
public class CustomView extends TextView {
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setTypeface(Typefaces.get(context, "fonts/NotoSansCJKjp-Medium.ttf"));
    }
}
```

Here is my xml layout in `main_activity.xml`

```
<com.example.user.fontchange.CustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ABC"/>
```

## EDIT 2:

Here is the `Typefaces` class

```
public class Typefaces {
    private static final String TAG = "Typefaces";

    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String assetPath) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                try {
                    Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                        assetPath);
                    cache.put(assetPath, t);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Loaded '" + assetPath);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface '" + assetPath
                            + "' because " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return cache.get(assetPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post your code when apply TypeFace, and where did you place the font file in Android Studio project?

Comment: @RameshKumar: I added my code. When I change text from `ttf` to `otf` (I have 2 fonts with the same name in my fonts folder), it works. Hope to see for reply

Comment: Typefaces class implementation?

Comment: @RameshKumar: I just added my Typefaces class. I think it is nothing special. I just send the path to it and load the font from asset.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontFormatException.html with this reference font did not converted properly..